# how to implement c# code/logic based on decision tree?

Tags: c#, logic, implementation, decision-tree

i have big decision tree with many Yes/No questions.

i need implement some code with c# and go trough this tree and get unique id as return.

```
if-> 1=true, A=true, C=true -> return 111;

if -> 1=true, A=true, C=false -> return 110;
```

how can i implement such a logic without if else?
my decision tree is much, much bigger as this sample and if/else are not good solution.
i think to do it in 2 methods. first Get QuestionID, and second method will get Unique ID of answer based on questions. please help me with some code ideas..

decision tree:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889301/how-to-implement-decision-tree-with-c-visual-studio-2008-help

Comment: no it is some different idea behind.. i couldnot find here some reasonable solution of my question. thatsway i asked it.

Comment: Why does decision 2 have 3 outcomes (4,5,6) in your diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a decision matrix. Your code will then look like:
discriminant = decision_matrix( 1, A, B, C, 2 )
switch (discriminant )
{
  case outcome_1: ...
  break;

case outcome_2: ...
  break;

default:
   throw ...
  break;
}

Answer (score 1):

if this tree is fixed you can set all alternatives in a decision table(somewhat like truth table) and save it in a dictionary then use this dictionary to return the corresponding outcome.

```
Dictionary["1,A"]=OutCome_1;
Dictionary["1,A,C,true"]=OutCome_2;
Dictionary["1,A,C,false"]=OutCome_3;
```

etc